# ManualEventReset - wait for any of both

Tags: c#, manualresetevent

Consider that I have passed two `ManualEventReset instances`

```
public void MyApiCall(ManualResetEvent ev1, ManualResetEvent ev2)
{
   //my code
}
```

Now, I have to '`WaitOne`' for any of both (no matter which of them, I need to to continue as soon as one of them raised signal). It is possible without changing api?

One of the solutions is spin lock:

```
while (!ev1.WaitOne(0) && !ev1.WaitOne(0)) 
{
   Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

But I wonder if there is some better solution.

Comment: You are looking for [WaitHandle.WaitAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc189983(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria ohh,  that was exactly what I was looking for. Maybe you should post an answer? :)

Comment: Why downvote? Is there sth unclear in my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [WaitHandle.WaitAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc189983(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example:

```
WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { ev1, ev2 });
```